# How to count amount of values by month then chart in a line chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I  want to count the instances for each month in my dataframe, then plot as a line chart, The Rep column has the same data every day i.e

```
    Date       Rep
0   2020-09-21  Me
1   2020-09-21  Me
2   2020-09-21  Me
3   2020-09-21  Me
4   2020-09-21  Me
```

how can I count the instances by month, then chart this as a line chart? Completely stumped

Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby("Date")["Rep"].size().plot()` for your data, or `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="M"))["Rep"].size().plot()` if your Date column is datetime.

Comment: @Screechie please accept my answer as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more months as sample data to show the line:

```
Date       Rep
0   2020-08-21  Me
1   2020-08-21  Me
2   2020-09-21  Me
3   2020-09-21  Me
4   2020-10-21  Me
```

You can use:

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%b-%Y'), sort=False)['Rep'].size().plot()
```

1. You can use `.dt.strftime` to select your format for `Date`
2. You must have a more recent version of pandas in order to pass `sort=False`, so that the line shows up correctly or you you'll have to use another mehtod.

[image]

Comment: @BigBen , sorry if it's confusing. Simply put, `kind='line'` is optional as 'line' is default.